# Selenium WebdriverIO does not see all texts of ReactJS list's options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, chromium, webdriver-io

comrades!

I bumped into an issue with getting a text from an element, what is an option of ReactJS drop-down list.
I mention, that version of webdriver is 3.6.0, Chromium - 63.

Snippet of DOM:

```
<div class="Select-menu-outer" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2">
 <div class="Select-menu" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2.0">
  <div class="Select-option is-selected is-focused" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2.0.$option-0-202004">Not started</div>
  <div class="Select-option" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2.0.$option-1-202001">In progress</div>
  <div class="Select-option" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2.0.$option-2-202002">Done</div>
  <div class="Select-option" data-reactid=".0.1.3.2.0.0.0.0.2.3.3.3.0.1.0.3.3:1.3.3.3.0.1.$0.1.0.0.$0.0.0.0.0.4.0.3.2.0.$option-3-202003">Undone</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript snippet (the drop-down list is open by this moment; I literally see the options on the screen):

```
$('div.Select-menu-outer>div.Select-menu').$$('div').map(elmt => {
        console.log('element - ' + elmt.getText());
      });
```

Output is:

```
element - 
element - 
element - 
element - Undone
```

I haven't seen such behaviour before. Have you?
I don't get it, why Selenium does not recognize the text of the first three elements but does recognize the last one's.

Could you suggest me something? Where should I dig into?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting situation. I will try to use this to see if this works:

```
$('div.Select-menu-outer>div.Select-menu').$$('div').map(elmt => {
    elmt.waitForText(3000);
    console.log('element - ' + elmt.getText());
  });
```